# how to add rows with same indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a row in dataframe like this

[image]

I want to separate each types of movies between '/' and add to the dataframe like this:

[image]

Thank you for any helps ^^

Comment: Please provide your `df` as text not as images

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try to research, and if you are stuck, post you code here and ask for specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your genre column by the delimiter and then explode on that column:

```
df['genre'] = df['genre'].str.split('/', regex=False)
df.explode(column='genre')
```